# Get latitude and longitude for map click

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mkmapview

Can anybody tell me that how can I get latitude and longitude of a location when clicking on map?

Answer (score 2):

You could try changing this to suite your needs:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/39374-mkmapview-tutorial-using-latitude-longitude.html

Answer (score 0):

Try google maps v3 api. Add an event listener to click and you can get latitide/longitude pretty easily. Ex:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    YourHandler(event.latLng);
});
```

event.latLng automatically gets the longitude and latitude of the location you clicked on